# where is the queue of pending requests stored?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

I am working on a network programming in unix with c++ . I have understood that listen () function is used to define BACKLOG (number of connections allowed to be saved in the queue) and accept () function starts to connect the first connection in the queue. Now, where in unix is the queue of connections stored ?

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ ? Because Unix is C. And I'm looking for that [listen()](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=listen%28%29) function, doesn't seem to be standard C++... Or it's from an external library ? Posix maybe? Please provide a reference.

Comment: Its C. Sorry, my bad .I am changing my tags

Comment: I think it is not even a C question. OP mentioned C functions, but his question is just about IP stack implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backlog of connections is stored in an internal kernel structure, you cannot traverse it directly but fetch it element by element by calling `accept()`, which is designed for that purpose.

Part of the information on pending connections is accessible via `netstat`, which under linux utilizes the `/proc`-filesystem for that purpose (i.e. `/proc/net/tcp`).